# Why unable to import pygal

Tags: jupyter, pygal

I'm trying to import pygal into my Jupyter Notebook but unable to do so.

```
import pygal

bar_chart = pygal.Bar(height=200)
bar_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
bar_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
bar_chart.add('Firefox', [None, None,    0, 16.6,   25,   31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1])
bar_chart.add('Chrome',  [None, None, None, None, None, None,    0,  3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3])
bar_chart.add('IE',      [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5,   66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1])
bar_chart.add('Others',  [14.2, 15.4, 15.3,  8.9,    9, 10.4,  8.9,  5.8,  6.7,  6.8,  7.5])
display(HTML(base_html.format(rendered_chart=bar_chart.render(is_unicode=True))))
```

Error message shown was "No module named 'pygal".
Can someone advise how can I resolve it?

Comment: Your post needs some details. You should post the full traceback of the error as text code here. Plus how you installed and are using Jupyter isn't mention and so we cannot provide the specific code to run inside a new cell in the notebook to try and fix things conveniently. You'd either run `%conda install conda-forge::pygal` or `%pip install pygal` in a new cell and restart the kernel and then try the import statements. But which one is a mystery for now.